# Copying a file on change using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher, copy-item

I am using a `FileSystemWatcher` to notify on file change, and then create a copy of that file:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Orders\"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
   write-host "Changed: $($eventArgs.FullPath)"
   $datestamp = get-date -uformat "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" 
   write-host $datestamp
   copy-item $eventArgs.FullPath "$(watcher.Path)backup-$datestamp"
}
```

Thus, if `C:\Orders\orders.xml` is changed, then `C:\Orders\backup-20131125121004` should be created. However, this is not working, and not producing errors. The notification does work, just not the copy:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Documents and Settings\sladministrator\Desktop> .\WatchBizSyncOrders.ps1
PS C:\Documents and Settings\sladministrator\Desktop> Changed: C:\Orders\New Text Document.txt
20131125100821
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(watcher.Path)backup-$datestamp"
```

to

```
$($sender.Path)backup-$datestamp"
```

Note that the variable inside the `$()` still needs a `$`. And the `$sender` automatic variable will always contain the object that generated the event.

Comment: This worked great! Thanks, I didn't know about `$sender`. My completed script is here for reference: https://github.com/mrichman/bizsync/blob/master/WatchBizSyncOrders.ps1